# Is there any way to retrieve and highlight the folder from the navigation pane in Outlook that the cursor is currently over?

Tags: c#, outlook, drag-and-drop, vsto

A bit of backstory; I've created a VSTO addin that hooks the DoDragDrop function in outlook and changes it so that you can drag directly from outlook into some third-party software that we use. The issue with this is that it screws with dragging and dropping inside of outlook. Because I'm converting the IDataObject to a different format outlook no longer recognises it and will make a copy instead of moving the mail item if it's dragged into another folder or dropped back on the main window. It's easy solved for the main window by hooking the RegisterDragDrop function and registering my own version IDropTarget class for that window and then I just move it programmatically but it's proving much harder when it comes to the folder pane.

I need to be able to get the folder that the cursor is over and preferably highlight it to? Or does anyone know another way of solving the issue of it copying instead of moving once converting it to the FileDrop format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the old IDropTarget interface by calling `GetProp(HWND, "OleDropTargetInterface")` before you set your own handler. You can then simply forward the call after you are done massaging the data